# Integrar ComboBox com TableView QT

Tags: sql, qt

Tenho uma tabela Cursos:

```
create table Cursos(
ID_curso int not null auto_increment,
Nome_curso varchar (50),
primary key (ID_curso)
)default charset = utf8;
```

E outra table cadastrados:

```
create table Cadastrados(
Nome varchar(50),
Matricula varchar(9) unique,
Curso_id int not null,
primary key (Matricula),
foreign key (Curso_id) references Cursos (ID_Curso)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Criando a interface com o Qt, eu consegui listar todos os cursos dentro de uma comboBox:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery("select nome_curso from Cursos");
ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
```

Mas agora eu quero selecionar algum curso da combobox, e fazer aparecer uma lista com todos os cadastrados desse respectivo curso (pensei em utilizar o tableView para isso). Mas eu não tenho a menor ideia por onde começar. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?